# facebook comment box in app

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-apps

I am fetching a facebook video and showing it in my app. I am also fetching the likes and comments with the help of this : 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/. doing same for likes.

code for showing comments:

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/video/embed?video_id='.$v[vid].'" data-width="470" data-num-posts="10"></div>
```

this actually posting the comments. but not for right things. i mean when i open that particular video from the facebook profile, the comment does not show there. and if i post a comment there, it does not show up in app page. i think the comment is posting for the url, not for the video object(or video id).
But like is working fine. I am using the same url for like button.
Hope i could make the question clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can embed this video into a page and after, you replace the link of the video by the link of the page.